# Janino compile several classes

Tags: java, janino

I have tried Janino and I'm able to execute a dynamic class, by passing a String to janino compiler.

Now, I should create several classed dynamically, and then import them into another dynamic class.

An example:

> - Compile class A from String
> - Compile class B from String
> - Create class C, putting inside "import mypackage.A; import mypackage.B; etc..."
> - Compile class C

How could I achieve that result?

My first dynamic class is:

```
package com.Flink.POJO;
public class RainPOJO {
    private String Altitude;
    private String City_name;
    private String Latitude;
    private String Longitude;
    private String Rainfall;
    private String Station_name;
    private String Time;

    public String getAltitude() {
        return Altitude;
    }

    public void setAltitude(String Altitude) {
        this.Altitude = Altitude;
    }
    public String getCity_name() {
        return City_name;
    }
    public void setCity_name(String City_name) {
        this.City_name = City_name;
    }
    public String getLatitude() {
        return Latitude;
    }
    public void setLatitude(String Latitude) {
        this.Latitude = Latitude;
    }
    public String getLongitude() {
        return Longitude;
    }
    public void setLongitude(String Longitude) {
        this.Longitude = Longitude;
    }
    public String getRainfall() {
        return Rainfall;
    }
    public void setRainfall(String Rainfall) {
        this.Rainfall = Rainfall;
    }
    public String getStation_name() {
        return Station_name;
    }
    public void setStation_name(String Station_name) {
        this.Station_name = Station_name;
    }
    public String getTime() {
        return Time;
    }
    public void setTime(String Time) {
        this.Time = Time;
    }
}
```

Then I have to call that class from the following class, generated dynamically:

```
import org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.MapFunction;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.DataSet;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.ExecutionEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.tuple.Tuple2;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.operators.base.JoinOperatorBase;
import com.Flink.POJO.RainPOJO;
public class FlinkExecutor {
    public FlinkExecutor() {}
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final ExecutionEnvironment env =  ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        env.setDegreeOfParallelism(1);

        Source Rain = new Source("sensor", "rain");
        String path_Rain = Rain.getCSVPath();
        DataSet < RainPOJO > ds_s1 = env.readCsvFile("file://" + path_Rain)
        .ignoreFirstLine()
        .pojoType(RainPOJO.class, "table", "time", "longitude", "latitude", "average_rainfall", "maximum_rainfall");
        ds_s1.map(new MapRain(ds_s1.count()))
        .print();
    }
}
```

To compile the first class I have used:

```
SimpleCompiler compiler = new SimpleCompiler();
compiler.cook(p_class);
ClassLoader classloader = compiler.getClassLoader();            
try {
    Class<?> cl = classloader.loadClass("com.Flink.POJO.RainPOJO");         
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

While for the second class, which contains the main method:

```
    SimpleCompiler compiler = new SimpleCompiler(); 
    compiler.cook(this.allClass);
    try {
        Class<?> cl = compiler.getClassLoader().loadClass("FlinkExecutor");
         Method mainMeth = cl.getMethod("main", new Class[] { String[].class });
         String[] methArgs = new String[] { "" }; // one input
         mainMeth.invoke(null, new Object[] { methArgs });

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The error I get is:
org.codehaus.commons.compiler.CompileException: Line 8, Column 7: A class 'com.Flink.POJO.RainPOJO' could not be found

Janino can't find the class import declaration.

Thank you,
Giacomo

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?  Maybe post what you have tried and where it's failing.

Comment: I have updated the answer with the code I used for my test.

Answer (score 0):

take the class loader from the first compiler, set it to the second compiler using `setParentClassLoader()`